# Returning the XML received on readystatechange - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

This is my first post here on Stack. I am trying to make a Get request which is succeeding but I am having trouble getting the responseXML into a variable for processing. I think I am supposed to be using a callback function, but I still can't get it quite right. I am hopeful that somebody can point me in the correct direction. Code below.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function buildOptions() {
            var data = null;



            /*xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
            if (this.readyState === 4) {
                console.log(this.responseText);
                callback.call(xhr.responseXML);
              }
            });*/ //This code block worked, but I couldn't figure out how to get the result back

            getXML = function(callback) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.withCredentials = true;
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                        callback(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                    xhr.open("GET", "http://URLRemoved");
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", "StringRemoved");
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("postman-token", "TokenRemoved");
                    xhr.send();
                }
            }

            function XMLCallBack(data) {
                alert(data); // These two functions were the most recent attempt but I'm still missing something
            }

            xmlDoc = getXML(XMLCallBack); // this is supposed to start the processing of the returned XML
            console.log(xmlDoc);
            var campaignName = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('self')[0]; //XMLDoc contains a null variable when I get to this line
            console.log(campaignName);
            var campaigns = ["","Freshman Campaign","Sophomore Campaign","Junior Campaign","Senior Campaign"]; //Code from here and below will be changing slightly once I can get XMLDoc to be correct
            var sel = document.getElementById('campaignList');
            for(var i = 0; i < campaigns.length; i++) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.innerHTML = campaigns[i];
            opt.value = campaigns[i];
            sel.appendChild(opt);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should move `open` ---> `send` outside the `onreadystatechange`, like this:

```
getXML = function(callback) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.withCredentials = true;
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    callback(xhr.responseText);
                }

            }
            xhr.open("GET", "http://URLRemoved");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", "StringRemoved");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("postman-token", "TokenRemoved");
            xhr.send();
        }
```

EDIT: This code should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function buildOptions() {

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
        xhr.onreadystatechange = XMLCallBack;
        xhr.open("GET", "http://URLRemoved");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", "StringRemoved");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("postman-token", "TokenRemoved");
        xhr.send();



        function XMLCallBack() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                xmlDoc = xhr.responseText;
                var campaignName = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('self')[0];
                var campaigns = ["","Freshman Campaign","Sophomore Campaign","Junior Campaign","Senior Campaign"];
                var sel = document.getElementById('campaignList');

                for(var i = 0; i < campaigns.length; i++) {
                    var opt = document.createElement('option');
                    opt.innerHTML = campaigns[i];
                    opt.value = campaigns[i];
                    sel.appendChild(opt);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I haven't tried it so I might have made some mistakes. If you want to, you can move `XMLCallBack()` outside of `buildOptions()` and use `this.readyState`, `this.status` and `this.responseText` instead of `xhr.readyState` etc..

Comment: Just a side note: The IE needs `xhr.send(null);`.

Comment: Thank you for the response Flott, So I made the change and now I am seeing the alert(data) function working correctly, but when I get down to using that data in the xmlDoc variable, that variable is still null. How do I store what is in data for use in processing?

Comment: Thank you reporter. I have been testing in chrome, but I will add that to my code so it doesn't trip me up when I get to IE

Comment: You can declare ´var xmlDoc;´ at the top of the script just underneath `var data = null;` then in `function XMLCallBack(data)` where you have `alert(data)` you can set `xmlDoc = data;` and change `xmlDoc = getXML(XMLCallBack);` to just `getXML(XMLCallBack);`. Note that since the XMLHttpRequest is an asynchronous mechanism you should move all code that needs the value of `xmlDoc` to the callback function, otherwise it will try to use the variable before it has been set in the response.

Comment: I updated my answer, try the modified code in my edit.